# npm XMLHttpRequest is undefined for third party library MyScript in nodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import, dependencies

I am using [MyScriptJS](https://github.com/MyScript/MyScriptJS)

And it was intended to be a graphical library, however they have a "No UI" example and I have used this in node REST API. I am getting an error;

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Is undefined. The fix is simple since this is not a web application I should just import it.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

My question(s):

1. Should I create an issue / pull request to introduce this import into MyScripts node package? `var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;`
2. Is there a way for me to introduce this dependency in such a way as to make it available to MyScript which I have imported in my application `import * as MyScript from "myscript"`? Hence allowing me to circumvent the issue of it being undefined in their package.
3. Since MyScript package does work within a React application. Surely this import is not always needed. Is there a way to conditionally import this package?